# How to check if diagram need to be save

Tags: c#, enterprise-architect

I need to check if diagram need to be save, because I'd like to show warning dialog before open my extension. I look at `Repository`, `Package` and `Diagram` classes and I found nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can know.
But you can save them for the user. One by one using Repository.SaveDiagram(long DiagramID) or all at one using Repository.SaveAllDiagrams()

Answer (score 1):

If you issue a Repository.CloseDiagram EA will prompt with a "Save Changes?". You can query the currently open diagram. So maybe you can combine that.

Comment: Yeah, but I want to show user "Save Changes?" without closing diagram ;)

Comment: I knew. Maybe you can ask for an API extension diagram.isModified. Don't hold your breath...

Comment: I have written to Sparx support already, but they haven't replied yet :/

Answer (score 0):

Response from Sparx:

> Thank you for your enquiry.
>
> Unfortunately there is no Property or
> Method currently available via the API to help determine if a diagram
> is in a modified/dirty state.
>
> We have logged a feature request on
> your behalf for this capability, but cannot say at this time if/when
> such a feature may be implemented.   Sorry we could not be of more
> assistance.